In LPDDR6, does Write store 2B System Meta Data into a bank's metadata registers? Is a MATA WRITE needed to store this data back into the array?
When Write or Read commands are issued to a LPDDR6 SRAM device, Meta-Write/Meta-Read
commands can be distinguished from normal Write/Read commands by PAMM segment hit or
miss in a target bank and associated column address (C[5:2]). Meta-Write/Meta-Read
operations shall be executed by WR-S/RD-S commands with C[5:0]=0x3C~0x3F. Issuing WRL/RD-L commands with C[5:0]=0x3C~0x3F is prohibited.
